# How to superimpose mask with python

Tags: python, mask

I created a IA using mask RCNN to identify specifics objects, and I need to superimpose the masks, not the image, of two or more images. Can someone help me?

I separated the masks and now i need to superimpose it.[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tEvc.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNoe4.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have your masks represented as np.arr. You can sum the two (or more) masks, and check which pixels are 1 or more. For example,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mask1 = np.zeros((128,128))
mask1[20:60, 20:60] = 1
mask2 = np.zeros((128,128))
mask2[50:80, 50:80] = 1
mask_combined = (mask1 + mask2 >= 1)
plt.imshow(mask_combined)
plt.show()
```